# Error for Sitting and Getting "value" in java Script

Tags: javascript, html, function, web-scraping, getelementbyid

I found this Error when I try to set or get a value on javascript

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getMood')
at getMood ((index):12:43)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):23:37)

could any body help me

Thank you :)

This is my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTEkq.png)

Comment: Can you please share the relevant code that is causing the issue?

Comment: Great, can you please use the [edit] button under your post to add this to your post, that way you can format it so it is readable.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)